# Calling android activity, getting it twice

Tags: android, android-activity

When I call a new activity with a button like this:

```
public void openRegister(View view){
    Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), RegisterActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

.. the activity opens. The view has a couple of textfields and stuff like that, but all of them are displayed twice. Email, password... and underneath the same thing again...Email, password...
Why is this happening?

My RegisterActivity looks like this:

```
public class RegisterActivity extends Activity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="MANGART"
    android:id="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="43dp" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Register"
    android:id="@+id/textView5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView3"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText3"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:hint="email"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText4"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText3"
    android:hint="password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPassword"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/editText5"
    android:layout_below="@+id/editText4"
    android:hint="repeat password"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Screenshot:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/POc9v.png

Comment: can you show the layout xml?

Comment: can you share the screenshot? and the above shared xml is of R.layout.activity_register?

Comment: yes it is. screenshot coming...

Comment: I used your code it show me the one time all edit text.

Comment: Fixed it, answered it, tnx for the help guys :)

Answer (score 0):

After some debugging and code revising I found out I set the android:theme to the "@style/FullscreenTheme" (the theme for the first Activity). Changed it to "@style/RegisterTheme" and created the "theme" and now it works perfectly.